# Import Customers Without Password

Tags: magento2, import, customer-account, migration, password

I am migrating a website from another shopping cart to Magento CE 2.2.6. I have been able to use the import function in the admin without an issue. The problem is that I won't be able to import any passwords. It seems that if I create an account without the password then the customer is locked out.
I would like to have the customer come to the Magento website and be asked to change their password when they try to login. That way I can put the same password for all migrated accounts.

I tried to change the `create_at` field in the customer account to more than 90 days old but that did not work. What is the proper way of importing customer accounts if you don't have the password?